# Python support sorted dictionary -- similar to C++ map?

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

I am using Python 2.7.x. I have a dictionary (I mean `{}`), key is int and value is string. I want to retrieve the key which has the minimal integer value. In C++, I think we can use map, which sort keys. And in Python, not sure if anything similar we can leverage? If my understanding is correct, Python dictionary (I mean `{}`) is not sorted by key.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: If you can sort in advance, maybe https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Related: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.2

Comment: @spectras, the values are added/removed dynamically, so in this way, we cannot sort in advance? Thanks.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks for sharing, and do you mean I maintain a normal Python dictionary and a binary search tree? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa: nope, you don't need the `dict`, an RB tree is enough to do both the associative container thing (key => value mapping is O(log n)) and the keeping sorted thing (`std::map` is normally implemented as an RB tree). Notice however that `dict` has O(1) lookup in the average case (like `std::unordered_map` in C++) and is written straight in C inside the interpreter, so, depending from the implementation, the RB tree may be considerably slower (especially if it's implemented in pure Python).

Comment: @MatteoItalia, good point, and using RB tree will make insert and remove slower, comparing to Python built-in hashtable?

Comment: @LinMa: anything requiring a lookup.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, it seems SortedDict is a better choice? How do you think? http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sorteddict

Comment: @LinMa: [they claim `SortedDict` is faster](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/implementation.html) than a tree-based implementation, but feel free to benchmark both and see what works best for you. From the usage standpoint they should be substantially the same.

Comment: Thanks @MatteoItalia, when you do benchmark for performance in Python, what API do you use or recommend? time.time()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

The OP has expressed a need for O(1) performance when finding the minimum key in a dictionary. Try the [`sortedcontainers`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/#sortedcontainers) module. It offers a [`SortedDict`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html#sorteddict) class:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
>>> d = SortedDict({100: 'a', 27: 'b', 1234: 'c'})
>>> d.keys()
SortedSet([27, 100, 1234], key=None, load=1000)
>>> d.keys()[0]
27
>>> d[d.keys()[0]]
'b'
```

---

For a Python builtin dictionary you can use `min(d)` to find the lowest key:

```
>>> d = {100: 'a', 27: 'b', 1234: 'c'}
>>> print(d)
{1234: 'c', 27: 'b', 100: 'a'}
>>> print(min(d))
27
>>> print(d[min(d)])
b
```

Comment: This is probably easier than using an ordered dict as per my solution.

Comment: Or, instead of sorting all keys, just take the minimum: min(d.keys())

Comment: @jgfооt: thanks! Actually that's what I was originally thinking to do, but forgot whilst writing the answer.

Comment: Or, if you want it as a key-value pair: `min(d.iteritems())`

Comment: It should be mentioned that `min()` will be O(n) instead of O(1) in the equivalent C++ code of `map.first()`. That may or may not matter depending on the needs.

Comment: Thanks mhawke, I think @KurtStutsman mentioned what I want to say, I am doing the same implementation as you are doing now, but the concern is min will be O(n) other than O(1). Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa If you're only interested in the minimum element, you could create a subclass of `UserDict` and override `__setitem__` to maintain the minimum value with an O(1) calculation. That would maintain the O(1) insertion and deletion that hash tables have. The C++ map uses trees which have O(log(n)) insert and delete.

Comment: @LinMa: OK. Perhaps you can try the `sortedcontainers` module. Check out the [`SortedDict`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html)

Comment: @KurtStutsman, thanks for the advice. I think maintain the minimal itself is not enough? Since when the minimal is removed, I need to know the 2nd minimal, which is the minimal for now. Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @mhawke, thanks for the advice, and it seems SortedDict is not Python built-in?

Comment: @LinMa: no, it's a 3rd party module. It is pure Python though and is generally considered to be of high quality and performance. Can't you use 3rd party modules?

Comment: @LinMa: only you can make that judgement. The testimonials are pretty impressive :)

Comment: Thanks @mhawke, make your reply as answered. Thanks again for all the help. :)

Answer (score 4):

In Python, dictionaries are represented internally by hash tables so you cannot natively get back the keys in sorted order. You can use `sorted(d.keys())` to return a list of keys in sorted order. You can also use `collections.OrderedDict` if you pre-sort the keys. If you do not know the order of the keys ahead of time and you need to maintain the keys in sorted order as you insert values, you could take a look at [this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers) for the SortedDict type.

Comment: You should probably mention that it is [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Thanks Kurt, if I need to add/remove elements dynamically (cannot be decided ahead of time), could I use and take advantage of OrderedDict? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa `collections.OrderedDict` only maintains items in insertion order not sorted order. That's why you have to know the key order ahead of time. The library at that link maintains sort order.

Comment: Thanks Kurt, let me confirm my understanding is correct as you provided multiple good references. :)

For the library you think resolve my issue, it is the SortedDict, other than the OrderedDict, correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are binary tree implementations in Python:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.2

You can also use the [`blist.sorteddict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/).

You could also use the built-in [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to maintain a sorted list of tuples.

If all you care about is finding the minimum and you don't actually care about maintaining a sort, you can use the built-in [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module to maintain a min-heap data structure which gives you constant time access to the minimal element.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @mhawke 's answer, you can simply do:

```
d = {1 : "a", 2 : "b", 3 : "c" }
print d[min(d.keys())] # => 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks Goodies, I am doing the same implementation as you are doing now, but the concern is min will be O(n) other than O(1). Your advice is appreciated. Thanks.